# Canvas drawImage drawing unwanted pixels when stretching

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I'm using drawImage to stretch a 1x2 pixel sprite into a 300x2 horizontal line.

This used to work perfectly fine, but recently I noticed a problem on Chrome, Firefox and Edge where the drawImage function would start including sprite data outside of the 1x2 defined box.
( Doesn't happen on mobile by the way )

In the below link, drawing the line works fine for small lengths, but once it goes over 255 pixels in length it will start drawing unwanted colours ( blue ).

JSFiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/y6bo1zfu/1/

```
var rawImage = false;

var testCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
testCanvas.width = 300;
testCanvas.height = 20;
var testContext = testCanvas.getContext("2d");
testContext.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
document.body.appendChild( testCanvas );

function loadImage()
{
    rawImage = new Image();
    rawImage.onload = function(){
        // Create the sprite image
        createSpriteImage();
        document.body.appendChild( rawImage );
    }
    rawImage.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
}

function createSpriteImage()
{
    testContext.drawImage(
        rawImage,
        2,      // Source X for this part of the Sprite
        1,      // Source Y for this part of the Sprite
        1,      // Width of this part of the Sprite
        2,      // Height of this part of the Sprite

        0,          // The X position where to draw
        0,          // The Y position where to draw
        300,        // Width of the line
        2           // Height of the line
    );

    testContext.drawImage(
        rawImage,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        2,

        0,
        3,
        298,
        2,
    );

    testContext.drawImage(
        rawImage,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        2,

        0,
        6,
        264,
        2,
    );

    testContext.drawImage(
        rawImage,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        2,

        0,
        9,
        256,
        2
    );

    testContext.drawImage(
        rawImage,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        2,

        0,
        12,
        255,
        2
    );

    testContext.drawImage(
        rawImage,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        2,

        0,
        15,
        100,
        2
    );

    testContext.drawImage(
        rawImage,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        2,

        0,
        18,
        10,
        2
    );
}

//
loadImage();
```

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Could this be a known bug or an accidental feature added through optimization?

Is trying to stretch an image 256 times its default width a no-no?

Comment: Sounds like when GPU kicks in (<250px, not on mobile etc.) Not sure you can do much on your side, except by exporting each sprite to their own ImageBitmap first. But do you really need drawImahe here, isn't fillRect or even putImageData more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Hardware Acceleration (HWA) i.e by the GPU. You can disable it on your own browser and you'll see it will work as intended.

Unfortunately you can't ask all your users to disable HWA.

One simple way to circumvent this exact issue is to create an ImageBitmap which contains only the required part of your image.
This is quite straight forward since the [`createImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) method accepts a 5 params version

```
createImageBitmap( source, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight );
```

and the `drawImage()` one accepts a 5 params version

```
drawImage( source, destinationX, destinationY, destinationWidth, destinationHeight );
```

You can thus rewrite your 9 params version `drawImage()` to

```
drawImage( 
  await createImageBitmap( source, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight ),
  destinationX, destinationY, destinationWidth, destinationHeight
)
```

```js
var rawImage = false;

var testCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
testCanvas.width = 300;
testCanvas.height = 20;
var testContext = testCanvas.getContext("2d");
testContext.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
document.body.appendChild( testCanvas );

function loadImage()
{
  rawImage = new Image();
  rawImage.onload = function(){
    // Create the sprite image
    createSpriteImage();
    
    document.body.appendChild( rawImage );
  }
  rawImage.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
}

async function createSpriteImage()
{
  testContext.drawImage(
    await createImageBitmap(rawImage,
      2,     // Source X for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,    // Source Y for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,    // Width of this part of the Sprite
      2      // Height of this part of the Sprite
    ),
    0,        // The X position where to draw
    0,        // The Y position where to draw
    300 ,     // Width of the line
    2      // Height of the line
  );
  
  testContext.drawImage(
    await createImageBitmap(rawImage,
      2,    // Source X for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,   // Source Y for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,   // Width of this part of the Sprite
      2     // Height of this part of the Sprite
    ) ,  
    0 ,       // The X position where to draw
    3 ,       // The Y position where to draw
    298 ,     // Width of the line
    2    // Height of the line
  );
  
  testContext.drawImage(
    await createImageBitmap(rawImage,
      2,    // Source X for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,   // Source Y for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,   // Width of this part of the Sprite
      2     // Height of this part of the Sprite
    ) ,
    0,        // The X position where to draw
    6,        // The Y position where to draw
    264 ,     // Width of the line
    2         // Height of the line
  );
  
  testContext.drawImage(
    await createImageBitmap(rawImage,
      2,    // Source X for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,   // Source Y for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,   // Width of this part of the Sprite
      2     // Height of this part of the Sprite
    ),
    0,        // The X position where to draw
    9,        // The Y position where to draw
    256 ,     // Width of the line
    2         // Height of the line
  );
  
  testContext.drawImage(
    await createImageBitmap(rawImage,
      2,     // Source X for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,    // Source Y for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,    // Width of this part of the Sprite
      2      // Height of this part of the Sprite
    ),
    0,       // The X position where to draw
    12,      // The Y position where to draw
    255 ,    // Width of the line
    2 ,      // Height of the line
  );
  
  testContext.drawImage(
    await createImageBitmap(rawImage,
      2,     // Source X for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,    // Source Y for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,    // Width of this part of the Sprite
      2      // Height of this part of the Sprite
    ),
    0,       // The X position where to draw
    15,      // The Y position where to draw
    100 ,    // Width of the line
    2 ,      // Height of the line
  );
  
  testContext.drawImage(
    await createImageBitmap(rawImage,
      2,     // Source X for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,    // Source Y for this part of the Sprite
      1 ,    // Width of this part of the Sprite
      2      // Height of this part of the Sprite
    ),
    0,       // The X position where to draw
    18,      // The Y position where to draw
    10 ,     // Width of the line
    2 ,      // Height of the line
  );
}

//
loadImage();
```

```css
body,html {
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #4f4f4f;
}
img
{
 display: block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 0px auto;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
canvas
{
  display: block;
 width: 300px;
 height: 20px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
 margin: 15px auto;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid white;
}
```

And for browsers that do not support the ImageBitmap interface, at least this usage can be monkey-patched by using other canvases.